# Date vindo com data de amanha em vez de hoje

Tags: javascript, node.js, data

O meu date esta vindo com a data errada, ta vindo a data de amanha mais eu quero a data de hoje. Para a minha aplicação a data e a hora não podem estar erradas.
Ja verifiquei a data no servidor e esta correta:
**data que devia vir**: 2020-05-29T24:47:00
**data que esta vindo**: 2020-05-30T02:21:04
Ele esta a 1 dia e algumas horas adiantado e não estou conseguindo arrumar

Codigo(Ele roda no NodeJS no Servidor):

```
var agora = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\..+/, '')
```

desde já agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema de fuso horário.

Comment: @anonimo  sabe como ajusto o fuso horário?

Comment: O quer colocar em `var agora` somente a data ou data e hora?

Comment: @ShintaroKisaragi você precisa verificar o timezone que quer aplicar, não ficou muito claro em sua pergunta, mas você precisa definir isso. se estiver utilizando sequelize basta aplicar "timezone": "Timezone que você quer", aqui tem uma lista https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: [Essa função](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332027/1377664) vai retornar a string que vc quer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

> A resposta original foi escrita inicialmente utilizando o método
> [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) que podia exibir data e horário numa mesma chamada.
> Na época em que foi escrito o código funcionava bem, porém com a evolução da
> tecnologia e constante adequação dos navegadores as recomendações da WC3 hoje a
> antiga funcionalidade do método `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` foi
> transferida para o método [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).
> Atualmente o método `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` apenas exibe datas
> enquanto o método [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) apenas exibe o
> horário.

Aparentemente a sua data não está vindo errada, você está tendo problemas com o fuso horário. Quando usa a função `toISOString()` você está retornando uma string em formato  [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) cujo o fuso horário é [Meridiano de Greenwich](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridiano_de_Greenwich) que é mesmo que [UTC zero]
[5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B0)

Para corrigir o problema você deve obter essa string usando um método que retorne uma versão temporal e culturalmente localizada desse horário e data. Em javascript esse método é [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

O método `toLocaleString()` retorna uma string com a representação culturalmente localizada do horário e data.
O método aceita dois parâmetros:

- locales: uma tag de idiomas no formato [IETF BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47).
- options: um conjunto de opções para personalizar a exibição da data. A lista dessas opções pode ser obtida na documentação [Constructor `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Veja os exemplos:

```js
//Cria uma objeto Date contendo a hora e a data atual. 
let dataAtual = new Date();

//Data e hora no Meridiano de Greenwich(da forma que estava fazendo)
console.log(`Data e hora no Meridiano de Greenwich ${dataAtual.toISOString()}`);

//Data e hora na minha cidade
console.log(`Data Hora em Campo Grande ${dataAtual.toLocaleString("pt-Br",{
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeStyle: "short",
  timeZone: "America/Campo_Grande"
})}`);

//Data e hora em São Paulo
console.log(`Data Hora em São Paulo ${dataAtual.toLocaleString("pt-Br",{
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeStyle: "short",
  timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
})}`);

//Somente a data em Manaus
console.log(`Data em Manus ${dataAtual.toLocaleString("pt-Br",{
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeZone: "America/Manaus"
})}`);

//Somente a hora em Fernando de Noronha
console.log(`Hora em Fernando de Noronha ${dataAtual.toLocaleString("pt-Br",{
  timeStyle: "short",
  timeZone: "America/Noronha"
})}`);

//Data e hora completa em Palmas
console.log(`Data Hora em Palmas ${dataAtual.toLocaleString("pt-Br",{
  dateStyle: "full",
  timeStyle: "full",
  timeZone: "America/Araguaina"
})}`);
```

Documentação adicional: Banco de dados de fusos horários IANA: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: Muito bom, não sabia daquela opção `timeZone`, vai ajudar imensuravelmente aqui ou ali. +1 :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe dá uma olhada nessa página https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil#IANA_time_zone_database tem a lista fusos horários brasileiros